# Выбор элемента из php массива по рандомному числу

Tags: php, массивы, случайные-числа, index

К примеру у меня есть вот такой массив:

```
$skins = [ 
  $skin = ['num' => 9000], 
  $skin = ['num' => 15000], 
  $skin = ['num' => 32900], 
  $skin = ['num' => 56000], 
  $skin = ['num' => 62300],
];
```

А также у меня есть рандомное число:

```
$rand_num = rand(0, end($skins['num']));
```

Допустим мне выпало число – **52390**, как мне исходя из этого числа выбрать элемент ближайшее к этому число в положительном порядке. Приведу пример

```
$rand_num = 4360;
// должно вернуть $skins[0];

$rand_num = 23904; 
// должно вернуть $skins[2];

$rand_num = 55433;  
// должно вернуть $skins[3];
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5464919/find-a-matching-or-closest-value-in-an-array

Comment: @splash58 Мне нужно не ближайшее, а положительно ближайшее то есть если `$i = [1, 8, 23]` и rand = 2 то нужен второй элемент, а не первый

Comment: значит сортируйте не по абсолютной величине, какие проблемы. или смотрите предыдущий индекс

Comment: массив отсортирован? что должн быть при  $rand_num = 100 433;

Comment: @splash58 что значит "массив отсортирован?", и $rand_num не может быть равно двум числам

Comment: *К примеру у меня есть вот такой массив:* - он отсортирован? я имел в виду $rand_num = 100000